# Naming output of a for loop for linear regression

Tags: r, for-loop, regression

I would very much appreciate any assistance with the code below. I've written a code to fit linear regression lines through a repeated dataset (individually and according to each patient id). What I really want is to be able to extract names/id with p-values above 0.05.

```
id <- c("A1", "A1","A1", "B10", "B10", "B10","B10", "B10", "C100", "C100", "C100", 
"G100", "G100", "G100")

weight <- rnorm(14, 70) 

height <- rnorm(14, 1.7)

A <- data.frame(id, weight, height) 


model1 <-function(weight, height){
anything<-lm(weight~height)
res<-round(summary(anything)$coefficients[, 4], 3)
res
}


model2<-function(weight,height){
res<-c()
for(i in unique(A$id)){
    res2<-model1(A[A$id == i,]$weight, A[A$id == i,]$height)
    res<-c(res,res2)
}

res
 }
```

The issue now is that I would like to name the output (res) according to the ids given in the data frame A (i.e. A1, B10, C100 and G100). I've tried adding `names(res) <- unique(A$id)` but this doesn't give me what I really want. Pls note that I'm not very experienced with writing loops so any suggestions for improving my code would be warmly welcome. 
I hope the question is clear enough but if not I would be happy to answer any queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c()` can take named inputs.  For example, if I want to create a vector with the names `x` and `y`, I can do so like this:

```
c(x = 1, y = 2)
```

In your case, when you append `res2`, you would name it:

```
res <- c(res, name = res2)
```

where `name` is the name you want to give it.

Just note, that it is much more effecient to preallocate the vector before the loop.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How do I ensure the names from A$id is tagged to the results? Note that my original data is much bigger than this so i wont be able to do it manually.

Comment: initialize/preallocate the container for the results like this: `ids <- unique(A$id)`; `res <- vector(length(ids), mode="list")`; `names(res) <- ids`; and then in the loop do `res[[i]] <- model1(A...`.

Comment: @fabians, your suggestion worked perfectly-just what I wanted it to do. Thank you so much, you've really made my day!